# Switch Case issue with default value

Tags: php, codeigniter, conditional-statements

I am running with some weird situation with `Switch Case` statement in PHP, where it is somehow ignoring the case and throwing default value. However this is not limited to the `Switch Case` only and happening with `if else` as well. So might be something wrong I am doing apart from conditional check.

I am using codeingiter and below I am posting all my code and helpers. I hope this would be enough information but let me know if you need any more information.

**Helpers**

```
// get employees
function get_employees(array $array = array())
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    return $CI->db->get_where('employees', $array)->result();
}

// get employee status from the `employment_status`
function get_employee_status($id)
{
    $result = get_employees(array('id' => $id));

    foreach ($result as $employee)
    {
        $status = $employee->employment_status;
    }

    return ($status !== '') ? $status : 'none';
}


// get employee status icon (based on status)
function get_employee_status_icon($id, $tooltip = TRUE)
{
    $status = get_employee_status($id);

    $get_icon = ($tooltip) ? 'rel="tooltip" title="' . ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $status)) . '"' : NULL;

    switch ($status)
    {
        case 'active':
            $status_icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ' . $get_icon . '></span>';
            break;

        case 'at_risK':
            $status_icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" ' . $get_icon . '></span>';
            break;

        case 'attrition':
            $status_icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" ' . $get_icon . '></span>';
            break;

        default:
            $status_icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" ' . $get_icon . '></span>';
            break;
    }
    return $status_icon;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function employees()
{
    $this->data['title'] = '<i class="fa fa-users"></i> ' . lang('emp_all');

    $base_url   = base_url() . 'admin/hr/employees';
    $numbs      = $this->employees_model->filter_count();
    $total_rows = $numbs['count'];
    $limit      = get_option('per_page');
    $page       = ($this->uri->segment(4) !== FALSE) ? (int) $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    get_pagination($base_url, $total_rows, $limit, 4, 2, TRUE);

    $this->data['results'] = $this->employees_model->fetch_rows($limit, $page);
    $this->data['links']   = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('hr/employees/index', $this->data);
}
```

**View file**

```
// view file
foreach ($results as $employee):

    do_print(get_employee_status($employee->id) . ' - ' .get_employee_status_icon($employee->id));    
    echo '<tr>';
    ...
    echo '<td class="status-' . get_employee_status($employee->id) . '">' . get_employee_status_icon($employee->id) . '</td>';
    ...
    echo '</tr>';
endforeach;
```

To clear things again: the code outputs the `default` value (icon) for the last `case`. It is ignoring the last case just only for the ICON and not for the tooltip or even `th` *class*

So how can I fix this where I can get output same as the case everywhere?

**EDIT: --- Added output images and var_dump image**

Please see the second last var_dump and output result to match the `at_risk` icon. Which is wrong

[image]

**HTML Output**

[image]

**var_dump()**

[image]

Comment: After `$status = get_employee_status($id)`, do `var_dump($status)`. That will show you what's going on.

Comment: Could be a lower case / upper case thing. Do the `var_dump` and you'll know more. Surely PHP is not broken ;-)

Comment: I did var_dump() before and again as per your direction. But same thing as I mentioned the function returning correct `tooltip` and `class` but not the `icon`

Comment: @CodeLover a mistake i found is `$status` will be `employment_status` of last value of `$result` **if really fetching multiple employees**

Comment: @karanthakkar where exactly you found in the code? I mean which function

Comment: if fetching multiple following lines are wrong . you are overwriting same variable.`foreach ($result as $employee)
    {
        $status = $employee->employment_status;
    }` if fetching single employee you need to clean your code. post controller where you are calling helper.

Comment: So how to fix it? any suggested solution?

Comment: @karanthakkar I have added controller, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should correct your this function by properly initializing $status variable;

```
// get employee status from the `employment_status`
function get_employee_status($id)
{
    $result = get_employees(array('id' => $id));

    $status = '';
    foreach ($result as $employee)
    {
        $status = $employee->employment_status;
    }

    return ($status !== '') ? $status : 'none';
}
```

Now, you should do var_dump of $status and see what you find in status variable value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did but no difference

Comment: Can you paste your var_dump response for $status, I assume you doing var_dump($status);

Comment: @chandresh_cool status should be `array` since he is fetching **multiple** employees. you are overwriting same variable and hence getting the last result as `$status`

Comment: That is ok. But let see what that array contains. I want to see the values are they mixed with upper and lowercase or something similar which is not present in switch case.

Comment: Actually var_dump is outputing html icon itself. Please wait a while I am updating question with some outputs